# What is this plant with white bracts around the inflorescence?

Tags: identification

Does anyone know the name of this plant? I live in North Georgia. [image]

Comment: Guessing the actual inflorescence + bracts are less than 3" across.

Comment: That looks remarkably like a member of the Monarda genus, very similar colouring and leaf shape to Monarda Clinopodia but the petals are so small that it makes me second guess. Do you have any other images, particularly with more mature flower heads?

Comment: This looks like two flowers...?  Please send more pictures.

Comment: Please send more information; opposite leaves? Shrub/small tree? Size of flower, is this one or two flowers? Is this a true photo? Please let us know...

Answer (score 5):

That looks like [Short Toothed Mountain Mint, *Pycnanthemum muticum*](http://www.abnativeplants.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=plants.plantdetail&plant_id=72).

[image]
[image: Picture from my yard]

Comment: Can you tell us more why you think it is this plant? Similar pictures or references?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Could be Whorled mountain mint or Pycnanthemum verticillatum. I looked it up on the inaturilist database. This is what i found:

also known as the Hairy Mountain Mint is easy to grow from seed and easy to care for once established.  It is clump-forming and can spread by rhizomes readily so is not the best native plant for small areas but roots can be easily cut back once a year to prevent spreading. The maximum height of 3' will be in average soils and full sun.  1-2' is more likely in drier soils and part shade.  The small white to lavender flowers have subtle purple spots and are packed with nectar inviting all kinds of bees, wasps, flies, beetles, moths and butterflies. It indeed is one of THE natives to have to attract pollinators.

Mammals, small and large, will not bother this plant due to its strong mint smell.  A simple walk-by and brush up against this plant will yield that familar mint fragrance. The leaves and stems are more hairy than other Pycnanthemum species, giving it its Common Name, Hairy Mountain Mint.  It is also referred to as Whorled Mountain Mint.